# sequelize Oracle -- table and field names are in upper case, so operations fail with invalid identifier for field names

Tags: node.js, oracle, sequelize.js

I am working on a Nodejs project with sequelize that can use mysql or Oracle as its database.    Looking at the oracle tables, I can see that it is creating tables and columns with upper case.

The sequelize module starts failing because it makes the db operations using lower case names (as provided in sequelize def file).

For example, this is the output trying to run a simple select query on a basic table with two fields.

```
Executing (default): SELECT "uuid", "name" FROM "PERSONS"  "Person";
Error fetching persons: DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: ORA-00904: "name": invalid identifier
Help: https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-00904/
    at OracleQuery.formatError (/home/rvnath/projects/comviva/RnD/ora/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/oracle/query.js:460:12)
    at OracleQuery.run (/home/rvnath/projects/comviva/RnD/ora/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/oracle/query.js:225:18)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /home/rvnath/projects/comviva/RnD/ora/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:315:16
    at async OracleQueryInterface.select (/home/rvnath/projects/comviva/RnD/ora/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js:407:12)
    at async Person.findAll (/home/rvnath/projects/comviva/RnD/ora/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1140:21)
    at async getAllPersons (/home/rvnath/projects/comviva/RnD/ora/index.js:53:21)
```

If I were to change the sequelize def file by turning the column names to upper case like below..

```
// define the person model.
const Person = sequelize.define(
  "Person",
  {
    UUID: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(8),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    NAME: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(32),
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    tableName: "PERSONS",
    timestamps: false,
  }
);
```

then it works fine, and here is the output.

```
rvnath@MCKL-2017 ~/p/c/R/ora> node index-working.js
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result FROM DUAL
Connection has been established successfully.
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "PERSONS" ("UUID","NAME") VALUES (:1,:2) RETURNING "UUID","NAME" INTO :3,:4;
Person inserted successfully.
Executing (default): SELECT "UUID", "NAME" FROM "PERSONS"  "Person";
All persons: [
  Person {
    dataValues: { UUID: <Buffer 12 34>, NAME: 'Ravindranath Tagore' },
    _previousDataValues: { UUID: <Buffer 12 34>, NAME: 'Ravindranath Tagore' },
    uniqno: 1,
    _changed: Set(0) {},
    _options: {
      isNewRecord: false,
      _schema: null,
      _schemaDelimiter: '',
      raw: true,
      attributes: [Array]
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  }
]
```

But this is not a workable solution, as I can't keep changing the sequelize def files for different db types.

Is there a proper solution to this?

Comment: See if your javascript module has a way to remove the double-quotes. Oracle is only case-sensitive in its object names if they were created with or referenced with double quotes. If you can't change that, consider simply passing your parameter object through another transformation that replaces the lowercase keys with uppercase ones for you. That way you can avoid working with uppercase in your code but it will still send uppercase to the database.

Comment: Suggestion is good, but not sure, how to remove the double quotes from the final sql. Will chk.